# How do you stop a Windows Batch file from exiting early?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-console

I have a windows batch file that looks similar to:

```
C:\DoStuff.cmd
move output.bak C:\newfolder\output.bak
```

The problem i have is that DoStuff.cmd executes a java program that once complete exits the batch run back to the command prompt. Line 2 never gets hit.

i have tried the following instead to execute the command in a new window:

```
start "My program" /WAIT C:\DoStuff.cmd
move output.bak C:\newfolder\output.bak
```

What happens with the above is that the new command window spawns the cmd file runs and exits back to a waiting command prompt and the window never closes, leaving the first command window waiting and the second doing nothing stuck after finishing step one.

How do i execute the first command without it having control of the batch run somehow?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [DOS call command](http://www.computerhope.com/call.htm):

```
@echo off
call C:\DoStuff.cmd
echo Exit Code = %ERRORLEVEL%
```

After getting error code you can proceed for example with:

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" exit /B 1
```