# How to prevent a bat file exiting early?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm running a maven plugin (this is just a new process) as part of a bat file.The plugin command causes the bat file to exit
so the subsequent commands do not run. Is there a command or some other way to prevent the
bat file quitting too soon ?

Here is the bat file :

```
ECHO Updating Version
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2

ECHO this echo does not occur
```

Perhaps I could use the 'call' command as referenced in [How do you stop a Windows Batch file from exiting early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485081/how-do-you-stop-a-windows-batch-file-from-exiting-early) but I would like to run all of the code within one bat file.

Comment: If mvn is a batch file, then you need to precede it with a call, or else it will terminate on that line.

Comment: What's wrong with using `call`? I don't quite understand what you mean by `run all of the code within one bat file`.

Comment: @user1161318 if you put your answer into a comment I'll accept it, thanks

Comment: Just set it as an answer; thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If mvn is a batch file, then you need to precede it with a `call`, or else it will terminate on that line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
set /p v=Press enter to exit
```

At the end of your program. This will wait for the user to interact before exiting.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **PAUSE** command.

```
Pause /?
```

Example:

```
@Echo off
Echo hello world
Pause >NUL
exit
```